# How to use LIS3MDL?

Tags: c, electromagnetism

I've successfully read registers of this magnetometer ([datasheet](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/54/2a/85/76/e3/97/42/18/DM00075867.pdf/files/DM00075867.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00075867.pdf)) and built numbers:

```
int16_t X = XL | XH << 8;
int16_t Y = YL | YH << 8;
int16_t Z = ZL | ZH << 8;
```

but these numbers don't look like vector coordinates. What are these?

So, this code:

```
float azimuth = atan2f(Y, X) * 180 / pi;
```

doesn't return correct value.

How to compute the real azimuth value?

Comment: What does the datasheet tell?

Comment: @Bence Kaulics, just how to _read_ these numbers, no how to _interpret_ it.

Comment: You shouldn't use bit shifts on signed numbers. On a 8- or 16 bit MCU this invokes undefined behavior. Change the code to `int16_t X = (int16_t) (XL | (unsigned int)XH << 8;)` and so on.

Comment: As for what the values represent, I would assume magnetic field strength as a raw value from 0 to max? The datasheet is wonderfully unclear, I would ask ST what the expected max values are. -32768 to 32767 doesn't make sense, because then one axis is longer than the other.

Comment: @Lundin, I not agree. When a magnet is close to the chip, values tend to -32768 or 32767.

Comment: @maestro Which doesn't make any sense if they are raw values. You'll have to ask ST how it makes sense to use two's complement and not one's complement to describe the axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do some more math to get rid of the device's offset.  The earth's field is usually about 0.3 to 0.6 gauss, and it is not parallel to the earth's surface, depending on your location.  Since the device's offset is typically +/- 1 gauss, your first challenge is to determine the offset.  You can do this by rotating the device.  If you have the device on a flat surface free from steel or iron, take a reading, and rotate it exactly 180 degrees, the first x and y readings will have the earth's field vector plus the offset, and the second will be the negative of the first reading with the offset still present.  By subtracting the two, you get two times the earth's field (the offset cancels out), and you can do the math as you described.  If you add the two, you will have two times the device's offset for the x and y vectors.  These offsets must be subtracted from the raw readings before doing the math as you suggest.  If you do not have a flat surface, and do not want to have to rotate exactly 180 degrees, you can take advantage of the fact that the sum of the squares of the three field vectors must add up to a constant value after the offset is removed, and do some math.  You will need a way to measure the gravity vector as well if you want to find azimuth without holding the device perfectly flat and normal to the gravity vector.  My iPhone apparently uses this approach on its compass app, but you must tilt/rotate the phone to calibrate.

Comment: Yes, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

In your case pi is a personal variable you will have declared somewhere. The define in math.h (the math.h I can see) is M_PI. Otherwise, you can still use "* 180 / (4*atan(1))" instead of "* 180 / pi". Quite efficient actually but in both cases, you will need to insert math.h.